# Get stuck with expired key of a removed package

Tags: apt, skype

After accidentally switching my repository, I got the

> failed to download repository information
> error from Software Updater.

I tried to do

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get  update
```

And found that I have an expired key for https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease. (Which I believe belong to skypeforlinux)
I uninstall and reinstall skypeforlinux, then revert the repository.
Now skypeforlinux has completely gone from my ubuntu software, and the expired key problem was not fixed. I tried to

```
$ sudo apt remove skypeforlinux
```

to remove the package, but I still got the key expired error.

I then did an even more stupid thing by removing the key:

```
sudo apt-key del <the expired key>
```

and got

> GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

instead.

It doesn't seem to be a serious problem, but is annoying. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Remove the package, and then delete the repositories from your system.  Microsoft has not updated the keys, or if they did they didn't tell people to install the newer keys before continuing to use it.

Comment: @ThomasWard I removed the repository and it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The Skype repository is a little wonky, as Microsoft has not updated the keys.  Partly because Skype is eventually going away, and Teams is going to be the 'replacement'.

The only way to get rid of the warnings about the insecure repository is to remove the repository from your sources and then run `apt update` - it will no longer try and query the repository and as such you won't get your "NO_PUBKEY" or "EXP_SIG" notices.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!